# Issue with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

I defined the following function:

```
sw[ θ_, ϕ_, h_] =  1/2 Sin[2 (ϕ - θ)] + h Sin[ϕ]
```

Based upon whether I use Solve or `NSolve`, I get different answers:

```
Solve[ sw[ π/2, ϕ, -1] == 0 && 0 <= ϕ <= π, ϕ]
```

I get different answers from:

```
NSolve[ sw[ π/2, ϕ, -1] == 0 && 0 <= ϕ <= π, ϕ]
```

The answer using `Solve` is complete and correct. However, with `NSolve` it only gives you a partial answer `ϕ == 0` but not `ϕ == π`.

Does anyone have any idea why *Mathematica* 9 is doing this?
How do I get the same answer from both the methods?

Comment: In my opinion `N*` methods use some predefined approximations,i.e. matching it with some predefined patterns which makes it fast.It might not be correct always and `M` gives this warning at times.

Comment: `N /@ Union[
  Round[#[[1, 2]], 10^-8] & /@ 
   Table[FindRoot[sw[\[Pi]/2, \[Phi], -1] == 0, {\[Phi], x}], {x, 0, 
     Pi, .1}]]`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I now have a consistent set of answers. Interestingly, the issue was occuring only when h = -1. In all other cases, both Solve and NSolve seemed to give the same answers.

Comment: @user9532 Welcome to `mathematica.SE`. If you want to interact with this site better, please register your account, so that when you collect votes you'll be able to do more on the site (adding comments, edditing posts, voting, etc.). See [privileges](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: This seems fixed in Mathematica 11.2. I got `{{\[Phi] -> 0.}, {\[Phi] -> 3.14159265358979}}` for NSolve.

Answer (score 9):

Although the both functions seem to be quite similar, nontheless one shouldn't expect that `Solve` and `NSolve` always yield the (same) equivalent solutions. The first returns **symbolic** (exact) solutions, while the latter gives **numerical approximations** to the solutions, behind the scenes they use different algorithms and different options are accessible, therefore we could expect appearence of various subtle issues.

The both functions basically assume that variables are complex, however in inequalities when algebraic variables are involved they are assumed to be real, let's take a look in the help page of `NSolve`:

> ```
> NSolve[ expr, vars]  assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically 
> in inequalities are real, while all other quantities are complex.
> ```

Thus it is ensured that `NSolve[ sw[ π/2, ϕ, -1] == 0 && 0 <= ϕ <= π, ϕ]` does the same as
`NSolve[ sw[ π/2, ϕ, -1] == 0 && 0 <= ϕ <= π, ϕ, Reals]`. One might suspect that some solution are omitted because they lie on the boundary  of the region `0 <= ϕ <= π`, nonetheless this input

```
NSolve[ sw[ π/2, ϕ, -1] == 0 && 0 <= ϕ <= 4, ϕ]
```

> ```
> {{ϕ -> 0.}}
> ```

either provides an **incomplete set of solutions**. This is of course an instance of **a bug** in **`NSolve`**.

On the other hand we can find a different route to get the full set of (numerical) solutions. Namely we are going to make `NSolve` select different algorithms imposing the **complex** domain. We can provide here two methods.

**1.** One method imposes a restriction on the real part of `ϕ`:

```
NSolve[ sw[ π/2,  ϕ, -1] == 0 && 0 <= Re[ϕ] <=  π,  ϕ]
```

> ```
> {{ ϕ -> 0.}, { ϕ -> 3.14159}, { ϕ -> 3.14159}, { ϕ -> 3.14159}}
> ```

**2.**  Another and even simpler approach explicitly includes the `Complexes` domain:

```
NSolve[ sw[ π/2, ϕ, -1] == 0 && 0 <= ϕ <= π,  ϕ, Complexes]
```

> ```
> {{ ϕ -> 0.}, { ϕ -> 3.14159}, { ϕ -> 3.14159}, { ϕ -> 3.14159}}
> ```

Now we can see that `Solve` and `NSolve` provided equivalent solutions.

Comment: +1. But strictly speaking, `Solve[expr,vars]` also **assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities are real, while all other quantities are complex** (according to the Documentation).

Comment: I agree, but I mean that `Solve` relies on different algorithms. To expose my argument once more: in  `NSolve[ sw[ π/2,  ϕ, -1] == 0 && 0 <= ϕ <=  π,  ϕ]` it is assumed that `ϕ` is a real variable. But taking `0 <= Re[ϕ] <=  π` or specifying domain `Complexes` it is assumed that `ϕ` is a complex variable, so that behind `NSolve` there work different algorithms which allow finding all solutions.