# Why the inequality does not take into account the domain?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, symbolic

I have this inequality:

```
Reduce[(4000-1000k)/(k-4) < 0]
```

and the answer is

```
k ∈ Reals
```

I would expect `k != 4`.

Comment: Perhaps because the lim k-> 4 of this is -1000?

Comment: This does not mean it is mathematically correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a kind of remedy for the problem at hand:

```
Reduce[# < 0 && Denominator[#] != 0]&[ (4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4)]
```

> ```
> k < 4 || k > 4
> ```

Even though the issues in the OP could be easily resolved nonetheless they are not mathematically correct and for this reason one could consider them as bugs, this is  a similar problem
( `4 ∈ Complexes` as well as `4 ∈ Reals` but `0/0` is `Indeterminate` thus
 `TrueQ[Indeterminate ∈ Reals]` yields `False`):

```
Reduce[(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4) ∈ Reals, k]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

while this one is correct:

```
Reduce[(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4) ∈ Reals, k, Reals]
```

> ```
> k < 4 || k > 4
> ```

Similar issue one can find here: [Issue with NSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391).

Therefore we can conclude

```
Reduce[(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4) < 0, k]
Reduce[(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4) < 0, k, Reals]
Reduce[(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4) < 0, k, Complexes]
```

> ```
> k ∈ Reals
> True
> True
> ```

yield  results which appear to be incorrect in special cases, they are only generically correct.
All of these above work as with a simplification technique:

```
Simplify[(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4)]
```

> ```
> -1000
> ```

but from strictly mathematical point of view they shouldn't. Nevermind what the documentation says (genericity et consortes) this is of course a bug:

```
Reduce[(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4) < 0 && 3 < k < 5, k, Integers]
```

> ```
> k == 4
> ```

Comment: I would not tag this as a bug as it seems to be by design.  Also, I'm not sure that from a practical point of view `ConditionalExpression[-1000, k != 4]` would be a better (more useful/usable) return value for that `Simplify`.  The function [FunctionDomain](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) is coming, which is a sort of practical solution to this problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs See the last line of the code, that is a bug. One cannot argue that's not since the domain `Integers` and the condition `3 < k < 5` selects only `k == 4` but for such a number `(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4) < 0` cannot be satisfied.

Comment: @Szabolcs By the way, do you know when the new version of  _Mathematica_ appears? Seems like it should be in a few days.

Comment: I don't know when it will appear.  The new documentation has been online for quite a while.  Are there any other signs that it's coming soon?  I wasn't expecting it just yet.

Comment: @Szabolcs I mean this question [Information on Mma v10](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/information-on-mma-v10).

Answer (score 2):

Please see this tutorial on the results given by symbolic functions. In short, the results returned by them are generically correct:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html

Answer (score 0):

In version 10, one could use this workaround:

```
Reduce[FunctionDomain[(4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4), k] && (4000 - 1000 k)/(k - 4) < 0]
```

`FunctionDomain` alone returns `k < 4 || k > 4` and can be used to restrict the domain of `k` within `Reduce` ...