# Eliminate variables by dividing two equations

Tags: equation-solving

how is it possible to divide two equations with Mathematica?

I have the following code:

```
eqn416 = a == Kp h (1 - E^(-ta/tau))
eqn417 = a/2 == Kp h (1 - E^(-ta2/tau))
```

Obviously one will get

```
2 E^(-(ta2/tau)) - E^(-(ta/tau)) == 1
```

by dividing them, but with

```
Eliminate[{eqn416, eqn417}, {Kp, h, a}]
```

I only get 'True'.

And if I try just to eliminate 2 of them and assuming afterwards 'a' is not zero

```
Eliminate[{eqn416, eqn417}, {Kp, h}];
%[[2]]
FullSimplify[%, a != 0]
```

I'm not getting rid of 'a'!

```
FullSimplify[a (1 + E^(-(ta/tau)) - 2 E^(-(ta2/tau))) == 0, 
 a != 0]
(* Out[434]= a (1 + E^(-(ta/tau)) - 2 E^(-(ta2/tau))) == 0 *)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Documentation Center told me that "`Eliminate` works primarily with linear and polynomial equations", so probably it's not the best solution here.

Comment: right, that's what I read too, but is there a better way?

Comment: When You try to eliminate only Kp and h You get 3 equations. When You apply `FullSimplify` to them assuming that a!=0, one of the results is the one You want. I copied the code block with %[[2]] from Your question and the result was the one You wanted.

Comment: This is closely related to [Why the inequality does not take into account the domain?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33616/why-the-inequality-does-not-take-into-account-the-domain), which points out some inconsistencies of equation-solving functionality. Having said that I recommend `Reduce` in such cases.

Comment: @Wojciech I had this solution too, but in my book the author takes the other ;) ... in addition, i'll get a different plot for those two solutions!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following. Here are your equations:

```
 eqn416 = a == Kp h (1 - E^(-ta/tau));
eqn417 = a/2 == Kp h (1 - E^(-ta2/tau));
```

and this divides one over another:

```
eq1=Inner[Divide, eqn416, eqn417, Equal]

(* 2 == (1 - E^(-(ta/tau)))/(1 - E^(-(ta2/tau)))  *)
```

Another approach:

```
 eq2=Equal @@ MapThread[#1/#2 &, {List @@ eqn416, List @@ eqn417}]

(*   2 == (1 - E^(-(ta/tau)))/(1 - E^(-(ta2/tau)))   *)
```

Have fun.

**A later edit** to address your question below: yes, it is easy:

```
  eq1A = Map[Subtract[#, eq1[[1]]] &, eq1]

(* 0 == -2 + (1 - E^(-(ta/tau)))/(1 - E^(-(ta2/tau))) *)
```

if you mean something of this sort.

Comment: is there a possibility to enforce a zero on lhs or rhs of an equation?

Comment: To enforce zero: HomogenizeEquation[eq_]:=eq[[1]]-eq[[2]]==0

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion:

```
eqn416 = a == Kp h (1 - E^(-ta/tau));
eqn417 = a/2 == Kp h (1 - E^(-ta2/tau));

DivideEquations[eq1_,eq2_]:=eq1[[1]]/eq2[[1]]==eq1[[2]]/eq2[[2]]

DivideEquations[eqn416,eqn417]

(* 2 == (1 - E^(-(ta/tau)))/(1 - E^(-(ta2/tau))) *)
```

Whenever you need to divide two equations then just call the DivideEquations function.

Comment: That's a good solution, more simple than the previous one.