# When and why are Assuming and Assumptions not equivalent?

Tags: symbolic, assumptions

In [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42109/12) there's an example of an integral where using `Assuming` and `Assumptions` give different results:

```
In[1]:= Integrate[Cos[n x], {x, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]]    
Out[1]= Sin[n π]/n

In[2]:= Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Integrate[Cos[n x], {x, 0, Pi}]]
Out[2]= 0

In[3]:= Integrate[Cos[n x], {x, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]]    
Out[3]= Sin[n π]/n
```

Now let's clear the system cache (or restart the kernel if you like) and try again, but now in a different order:

```
In[4]:= ClearSystemCache[] (* fresh start! *)

In[5]:= Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Integrate[Cos[n x], {x, 0, Pi}]]
Out[5]= 0

In[6]:= Integrate[Cos[n x], {x, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]]
Out[6]= 0
```

To make things even more weird, the results are affected by the order these two versions are evaluated (clearly due to caching).  `In[6]` and `In[3]` are the same but they return different results.

I always assumed that using `Assuming` or `Assumptions` with built-in functions should be equivalent.  It seems this is not true.  I can imagine that `Integrate` uses something internally (e.g. `Refine`) that is affected by the global `Assuming`, but not by `Assumptions`.

Generally, when are `Assuming` and `Assumptions` not equivalent?

Is the result I quoted above a bug?

---

**EDIT:** As Artes and Michael noted in the comments, this is explained by Daniel Lichtblau [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19894/12).  My only remaining worry is that the results are cached and effectively depend on the order of evaluation.

Comment: I remember Daniel Lichtblau answered such a question (or closely related) more or less one year ago.

Comment: @Artes This one? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19894

Comment: @MichaelE2 Perheps I remembered this one but not quite sure at the moment.

Comment: @Artes So then both this one and [the other one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42109/mathematica-gives-wrong-simplification-why) are practically duplicates of that question.  Do you agree?

Comment: @Szabolcs I marked the other question as a duplicate, but I think the problem you pointed out here (dependence on the order of evaluation) is worth of explanation.