# Puzzled by Assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, assumptions

I don't know if this has already been discussed.

```
Integrate[BesselJ[2 m + 1, x], {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> m ϵ Integers]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[1, Re[m] > -1]`

```
Integrate[BesselJ[2 m, x], {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> m ϵ Integers]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[1, Re[m] > -(1/2)]`

```
Assuming[m ∈ Integers, Integrate[BesselJ[2 m + 1, x], {x, 0, ∞}]]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[1, m > -1]`

```
Assuming[m ∈ Integers, Integrate[BesselJ[2 m, x], {x, 0, ∞}]]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[1, m > -(1/2)]`

Why doesn't *Mathematica* consider the evenness or oddness of the 1st argument (i.e., `2 m` or `2 m + 1`)?

Comment: @Karsten 7: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Related (possibly duplicates): [(19833)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19833), [(42114)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42114) -- See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19894/4999) to (19833) especially.

Comment: Thanks for the links. However here the situation is different. `Assuming[{k ∈ Integers}, Integrate[ Exp[ I k t], {t, -π, π}]]` returns an incorrect result whereas `Integrate[ Exp[ I k t], {t, -π, π},Assumptions->k ∈ Integers]` returns the correct one. Here it seams that Integrate simply ignores (or cannot take into account) the `Assumptions` and proceed to its evaluation of the integrand without any `Assumptions` for both of the cases.

Comment: I think [Daniel's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19894/4999) explains it: Try `Simplify[Integrate[Exp[I k t], {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},  Assumptions -> k \[Element] Integers], k \[Element] Integers]`.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelE2.

Comment: Michael and Daniel thanks for the comments. I read many times Daniel's reply but still I cannot understand what it is the connection with the current situation. Can you elaborate more in this issue? For me is like `Integrate` cannot utilize the included `Assumptions` so it treats `Integrate[BesselJ[2 m, x], {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> m ϵ Integers]` as simple `Integrate[BesselJ[2 m, x], {x, 0, ∞}]`. Am I correct?

Comment: sorry, what is the expected result? Is this page wrong too? http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/02/01/

Comment: Daniel's answer implies that the `Assuming` result should be like the one in which you `Simplify` the `Assumptions` result like this: `With[{res = Integrate[BesselJ[2 m + 1, x], {x, 0, ∞},  Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers]}, Assuming[m ∈ Integers, Simplify[res]]]`, which it is.  (If `$Assumptions` is used elsewhere in computing the integral, one might get other differences, too, I suppose.) See also [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97195/4999), which coincidentally came up a little after your question.