# Need help understanding the output of `DSolve`

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I give *Mathematica* 10 the following command:

```
DSolve[I D[P[x], {x, 2}] f[x] - (P'[x])^2 f[x] + 2 I P'[x] f'[x] == 0, P, x]
```

and I have the following output:

```
{{P -> Function[{x}, C[2] - I Log[C[1] - Integrate[-(I/f[K[1]]^2), {K[1], 1, x},
 Assumptions -> True]]]}}
```

What does `Assumptions -> True` mean? Which assumptions? I didn't make any assumption.

Comment: It's probably artifact due to the lack of information about the integrability of `1/f^2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assumptions -> True` is the default for no assumptions.  Setting this may seem unnecessary, but it overrides [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html).  One can see this in the following:

```
Integrate[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

Block[{$Assumptions = k ∈ Integers},
 Integrate[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
 ]

Block[{$Assumptions = k ∈ Integers},
 Integrate[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> True]
 ]
(*
  (2 Sin[k π]^2)/k
  0
  (2 Sin[k π]^2)/k
*)
```

So `DSolve` is protecting the solution it returned by using the option.

Ref: [Usage of Assuming for Integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration/19894#19894)