# General integral does not match special case?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider the following function:

```
f = (E^(2 I c \[Phi]) - (E^(2 I \[Phi]))^c) (E^(2 I \[Phi]))^n
```

Integrating this function with respect to `\[Phi]` from `-\[Pi]` to `\[Pi]` apparently gives:

```
int1 = Integrate[ f , {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

> [image]

Suppose we would like `n` to be an integer, so we fully simplify as follows:

```
Assuming[Element[n, Integers], int1 // FullSimplify]
```

> [image]

which, in general, is a non-zero quantity. However, for integer `n` we should be able to do the integral directly with this assumption in place. This suggests:

```
int2 = Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Integrate[ f , {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}] ]
```

> 0

Now it seems that the integral is actually zero for general integer `n`! Surely, only one of the two results can be true. Which one is it? And why is Mathematica producing these discrepancies? Is this a bug in Mathematica?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Usage of Assuming for Integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19833/34893) and links therein.

Comment: $$int2 = Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Integrate[ f , {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}] ]$$ Mathematica gives  a *nonzero answer* for  *nonIntegral value* of $c$ (Works fine ) otherwise it gives $0$ (a wrong answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a proper usage of "Assumptions" for integration, Please go through the post:
[Proper usage of Assumptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97164/44142)

Following works fine for your case.

```
  Block[{$Assumptions = n \[Element] Integers}, Integrate[f, {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Assumptions -> True]]
```

This gives: 
$\frac{\sin (2 \pi  (c+n))-2 \sin (\pi  (c+n))}{c+n}$; which can be simplified to your first answer.