# Adding more specific assumptions to Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, trigonometry

Let's say I would like to find a symbolic form for the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^nx\,\mathrm{d}x$$with the added condition that $n$ is not only an integer, but an even one at that. Can this be done?

I've tried

```
Integrate[Sin[x]^n, {x, 0, 2Pi}, Assumptions -> {n == 2k && k ϵ Integers}]
```

but this seems to ignore the `k` altogether.

I didn't expect this to work, but I've also tried using

```
Assumptions -> {n ϵ Integers && EvenQ[n] == True}
```

but that only returns `Integrate[..., Assumptions -> {False}]`.

**Edit:** I realize I could replace `n` with `2n` and just use `Assumptions -> n ϵ Integers`, but is there a way to compound the even/integer conditions in `Assumptions`?

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97154/puzzled-by-assumptions and the referenced post. Hope it helps.

Comment: Check your bracketing.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96890/4999

Answer (score 1):

```
Assuming[{n/2 ∈ Integers},
  Integrate[Sin[x]^n, {x, 0, 2 π}]] //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Assuming[{n >= 0 && n/2 ∈ Integers},
  Integrate[Sin[x]^n, {x, 0, 2 π}]] //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
Assuming[{n >= 0 && n/2 ∈ Integers},
  Integrate[Sin[x]^n, {x, 0, 2 π}] //
   FullSimplify] //
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's actually rather easy to specify the evenness or oddness of an integer in an assumption:

```
Assuming[Mod[k, 2] == 0, Integrate[Sin[x]^k, {x, 0, 2 π}]]
   (* (2 Sqrt[π] Gamma[(1 + k)/2])/Gamma[1 + k/2] *)

Assuming[Mod[k, 2] == 1, Integrate[Sin[x]^k, {x, 0, 2 π}]]
   (* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
Integrate[Sin[x]^(2 n), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
Assumptions -> {n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers}]
//TraditionalForm
```

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left((-1)^{2 n}+1\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$