# Using `NIntegrate` or `Integrate` with unspecified constants

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a function defined like :

```
g[n_, x_] := ((n + 2)*Cos[π*(n + 2)*x] - Cot[π*x] *Sin[(n + 2)*π*x])
```

and I want to do the following :

```
Integrate[x*g[n, x]*g[m, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

But this results in the error :

> Integrate::idiv: Integral of x ((2+m) Cos[(2+m) π x]-Cot[π x] Sin[(2+m) π x]) ((2+n) Cos[(2+n) π x]-Cot[π x] Sin[(2+n) π x]) does not converge on {0,1}.

On the other hand, if I specify values of `n` and `m` it gives me a numerical output, as desired. Experimenting with the numbers, I have been able to determine that whenever `m = n + odd#`, where odd# is any odd number > 1,  the integral is zero within machine precision.

```
Table[Integrate[x*g[n, x]*g[n + i, x], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 3}, {i, 3}]
```

Results in :

```
{{-(6656/(735*Pi^2)), 0, -(2816/(2835*Pi^2))}, {-(15872/(945*Pi^2)), 0, -(72704/(38115*Pi^2))}, {-(1013504/(38115*Pi^2)), 0, -(1801216/(585585*Pi^2))}}
```

Considering the above, can someone please guide me how I can obtain the output of `Integrate` as a function of `n` or `n` and `m`? One way I can think of is to find the relation between coefficients of my output but I can't figure out how to do that by hand or by any code.

Edit : Inspired from comments I tried the following to check for specific cases of `n` and `m` values. Here I take `m=n+3` which I have verified works for n upto 10 (atleast).

````
Integrate[x*g[n, x]*g[n + 3, x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] {1, 2, 3}}] (* Fails *)

Integrate[x*g[n, x]*g[n + 3, x], {x, 0, 1}] /. n -> 1 (* Works *)
Integrate[x*g[n, x]*g[n + 3, x], {x, 0, 1}] /. n -> 2 (* Works *)
Integrate[x*g[n, x]*g[n + 3, x], {x, 0, 1}] /. n -> 3 (* Works *)

```
````

Comment: `Assumptions` or `Assuming` is the way to go. See e.g. [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213218/integral-int-d-1d-2-int-l-2l-2-int-l-2l-2-frac1x2y2/213223#213223), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration) or [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/when-and-why-are-assuming-and-assumptions-not-equivalent).

Comment: @Artes I tried `Integrate[x*g[n, x]*g[n, x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers}]` which provided me with output `Integrate::idiv: Integral of x ((2+n) Cos[(2+n) \[Pi] x]-Cot[\[Pi] x] Sin[(2+n) \[Pi] x])^2 does not converge on {0,1}.` Could you please look into this more? I am also trying to read all the discussion on the links you provided.

Comment: This integral is divergent because you have `Cot[Pi x]` in `g` which diverges when `x` goes to `0` and when it goes to `1`.

Comment: @Artes Then `Mathematica` shouldn't provide a finite value when I specify the value of `n` and `m`, right? But it does as can be seen from the question I posted.

Comment: When you specify `n` and `m` Integrate can calculate specified case, in general seems it cannot.  Try to rewrite  your integrand to get rid of `Cot` putting e.g. `Cos/Sin`. Perhaps you should  also try  the `PrincipalValue` option in `Integrate`.

Comment: @Artes I will try that and get back to you. Can you also please look at the details under the edit I just made? It seems the error isn't with `Mathematica` not knowing the value of `n`.