# Solve[Tan[theta] == (b*Sin[t])/(a*Cos[t]), theta] breaks when "Reals" is added?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, trigonometry

*Mathematica* solves this equation fine:

```
Solve[ Tan[theta] == (b*Sin[t])/(a*Cos[t]), theta] // InputForm
```

> ```
> {{theta -> ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[(b*Tan[t])/a] + Pi*C[1], 
>   Element[C[1], Integers]]}}
> ```

The solution is real when $a$, $b$, and $t$ are real (and $t$ isn't a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$). However, adding the `Reals` condition breaks things:

```
Solve[ Tan[theta] == (b*Sin[t])/(a*Cos[t]), theta, Reals] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
>
> Solve[Tan[theta] == (b*Tan[t])/a, theta, Reals]
> ```

Why?

Comment: `Reduce` seems to be doing better on this.

Comment: The superficial reason is that specifying a domain restricts which algorithms will be applied.

Comment: @Artes still reading over your answer, plan to upvote/approve soon. Very complete!

Comment: @barrycarter It appears that  a complete explanation of the issue is quite hard since documentation pages doesn't tell the full story and internal implementation changes significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue we encounter here is an apparent incompleteness of the recent updates in the system, we should remember that 
`Solve` has been updated in the recent versions of *Mathematica* and although documentation pages say "last modified in *8*", one can distinguish various different issues between *ver.8* and *ver.9*, it's just a state of art.  In *ver. 8* we get:

```
Solve[ Tan[θ] == b Sin[t]/(a Cos[t]), θ]
```

> ```
> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so 
> some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> {{θ -> ArcTan[(b Tan[t])/a]}}
> ```

while in  *ver. 9*

```
Solve[ Tan[θ] == b Sin[t]/(a Cos[t]), θ]
```

> ```
> {{θ -> ConditionalExpression[ArcTan[(b Tan[t])/a] + π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
> ```

even though `ConditionalExpression` was added in *ver.8*.

There are more substantial issues, but the one above shows that we shouldn't expect behind the scenes a simple procedure yielding always predictable results.

By default underlying variables are assumed to be complex (if there are no algebraic inequalities) and  then `Solve` returns a **generic** solution, thus it isn't as fine as one seems to believe.  When we restrict the domain to `Reals` a bug may appear, see e.g. [Issue with NSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391) thus effectively domain specification may be regarded as an application of a different algorithm for searching the solution space. 
Specifying the domain one can exploit an option `Method` in `Solve` which by default is `Automatic`, see `Options[ Solve, Method]`.

Whenever attempting to solve a transcendental equation involving a few symbolic variables (parameters) it is recommended using `Reduce` or at least `Solve` with the [`MaxExtraConditions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html?q=MaxExtraConditions&lang=en) option to get more information on the solution space, however the latter **cannot always guarantee** fully **equivalent solution** (one can find here a [remarkable example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph/33952#33952)), thus encountering more symbolic variables we would rather exploit `Reduce`.

Sometimes even apparently simple equations can be hard to solve symbolically, for more detailed discussion see [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129).
Here we use `Solve` in  `Reals`:

```
θ /. Solve[ Tan[θ] == b Sin[t]/(a Cos[t]), θ, Reals, Method -> Reduce]
```

> ```
> {ConditionalExpression[ 
>      2 ArcTan[( Cot[t] (-a - b Tan[t] Sqrt[( Cot[t]^2 (a^2 + b^2 Tan[t]^2))/b^2]))/b]
>    + 2 π C[1], (C[1] ∈ Integers && b > 0 && Tan[t] > 0) || 
>                (C[1] ∈ Integers && b > 0 && Tan[t] < 0) || 
>                (C[1] ∈ Integers && b < 0 && Tan[t] > 0) || 
>                (C[1] ∈ Integers && b < 0 && Tan[t] < 0)], 
>  ConditionalExpression[
>      2 ArcTan[( Cot[t] (-a + b Tan[t] Sqrt[(Cot[t]^2 (a^2 + b^2 Tan[t]^2))/b^2]))/b] 
>    + 2 π C[1], (C[1] ∈ Integers && b > 0 && Tan[t] > 0) || 
>                (C[1] ∈ Integers && b > 0 && Tan[t] < 0) || 
>                (C[1] ∈ Integers && b < 0 && Tan[t] > 0) || 
>                (C[1] ∈ Integers && b < 0 && Tan[t] < 0)]}
> ```

slightly more detailed information would be found with:

```
Solve[ Tan[θ] == b Sin[t]/(a Cos[t]), θ, Reals, Method -> Reduce, 
       MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

or

```
Reduce[ Tan[θ] == b Sin[t]/(a Cos[t]), θ, Reals]
```

Alternatively we should assume that all variables are real by suplementing the equation with `a > 0 && b > 0 && t > 0 && θ > 0` without explicit domain specification:

```
θ /. Solve[ Tan[θ] == b Sin[t]/(a Cos[t]) && 
                a > 0 && b > 0 && t > 0 && θ > 0, θ]
```

> ```
> {ConditionalExpression[ ArcTan[(b Tan[t])/a], 
>    (a > 0 && b > 0 && 0 < t < π/2) ||
>    (C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] >= 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && π C[1] < t < 1/2 (π + 2 π C[1]))]}, 
>
>  ConditionalExpression[ ArcTan[(b Tan[t])/a] + π C[2], 
>    ((C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && 0 < t < π/2 && C[2] >= 1 && a > 0 && b > 0)   ||
>    ((C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && 1/2 (-π + 4 π C[1]) < t < 1/2 (π + 4 π C[1])
>      && C[1] >= 1 && C[2] >= 1 && a > 0 && b > 0)                                ||
>    ((C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && 1/2 (π + 4 π C[1]) < t < 1/2 (3 π + 4 π C[1])
>      && C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 1 && a > 0 && b > 0)]}}
> ```