# Finding parameters making real part of eigenvalues vanish

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, polynomials

I have the following $\;3\times3$ matrix:

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.04 -0.4 b & 0 & 0.04 -0.4 b \\
 0 & -0.08-1.2 b & -0.06-0.9 b \\
 1.04 -0.4 b & 2.08 -0.8 b & 0
\end{array}
\right)$

I want to find the $b$ values that make any of the eigenvalues of this matrix is $0$.

When I calculate the eigenvalues I get the following:

> ```
> {Root[- 0.00832 - 0.0384 b + 1.264 b^2 - 0.48 b^3 + (0.08 + 2.24 b - 0.4 b^2) #1
>       + (0.04 + 1.6 b) 2 + 1. #1^3&, 1], 
>  Root[- 0.00832 - 0.0384 b + 1.264 b^2 - 0.48 b^3 + (0.08 + 2.24 b - 0.4 b^2) #1
>       + (0.04 + 1.6 b) #1^2 + 1. #1^3&, 2],
>  Root[- 0.00832 - 0.0384 b + 1.264 b^2 - 0.48 b^3 + (0.08 + 2.24 b - 0.4 b^2) #1
>       + (0.04 + 1.6 b) #1^2+1. #1^3&, 3]}
> ```

Now I want to get the $b$ value that makes the real part of any of the eigenvalues $0$ with the following command:

```
Map[ NSolve[ Re[#] == 0 && b ∈ Reals, b] &, eigs]
```

*Mathematica* finds that the real part of the first eigenvalue will never be $0$, hence produces an empty set. However, for the roots $2$ and $3$, it does not evaluate the command. Also, first root is 0 when $b=0.1$ as I can see it in the plot below (red dots).

[image: Eigenvalues with respect to $b$]

Is there any way to find $b$ more effectively?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since *Mathematica* offers powerful symbolic capabilities I find that more effective solution to the problem uses exact numbers instead of machine precission ones and consequently exploits appropriate symbolic functions.

The given matrix `m`:

```
m = {{0.04 - 0.4 b, 0, 0.04 - 0.4 b}, 
     {0, -0.08 - 1.2 b, -0.06 - 0.9 b}, 
     {1.04 - 0.4 b, 2.08 - 0.8 b, 0}};
```

we rewrite it to exact (rational) numbers:

```
matrix = Rationalize @ m
```

> ```
> {{  1/25 - (2 b)/5,                 0,   1/25 - (2 b)/5   }, 
>  {               0, -(2/25) - (6 b)/5,  -(3/50) - (9 b)/10}, 
>  { 26/25 - (2 b)/5,   52/25 - (4 b)/5,                   0} }
> ```

Now we can do simply this

```
sol = Solve[ Thread[ Eigenvalues[ matrix] == 0], b]
```

> ```
> {{b -> -(1/15)}, {b -> 1/10}, {b -> 13/5}}
> ```

Instead of `Thread[ Eigenvalues[matrix] == 0]` one could write  `Eigenvalues[matrix] == {0, 0, 0}`.

However this solution might be misleading since only **one eigenvalue can vanish** for  every "solution" `b` while we explicitely **required that all the eigenvalues vanish**. `Solve` gives generic solutions (see e.g. [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)) thus if we are to find `b` when every eigenvalue vanishes then an appropriate approach exploits the `MaxExtraConditions` option of `Solve` or switches to `Reduce`:

```
Solve[ Thread[ Eigenvalues[matrix] == 0], b, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

```
 Reduce[ Eigenvalues[matrix] == {0, 0, 0}, b]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

In fact, one can be surprised that simple usage of `Solve` seemingly appears to be flawed, nevertheless the `Root` objects are responsible for this issue and basically it is an instance of inevitable **operational incompatibility** of different symbolic functions.

Now let's look at the output we can get with `Solve`:

```
matrixS = matrix /. sol;
MatrixForm /@ matrixS
```

[image]

and these are  eigenvalues

```
 Eigenvalues /@ matrixS
```

> ```
>  {{    1/30 (1 + Sqrt[65]),    1/30 (1 - Sqrt[65]),    0},
>   { 1/10 (-1 + I Sqrt[29]), 1/10 (-1 - I Sqrt[29]),    0},
>   {                -(16/5),                     -1,    0} }
> ```

**Edit**

To underline that curious  behaviour mentioned above  let's consider eigenvalues in terms of `Root[ poly[b], k]` objects involving a parameter `b` with different numbers `k`. **A critical issue** is to realize that enumeration of roots depends on their values and may change when `b` changes. This plot  clarifies the problem, here we use:

```
rt[k_] := Root[-26 - 120 b + 3950 b^2 - 1500 b^3 + (250 + 7000 b - 1250 b^2) #1 
               + (125 + 5000 b) #1^2 + 3125 #1^3 &, k] /. b -> x + I y /. x -> 1/10

Plot[ Re[ rt[#]& /@ {1, 2, 3}], {y, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.006], ImageSize -> 560, 
      PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]]
```

[image]

The above problems may be prevented with `ToRadicals`, compare e.g.

```
Solve[ Root[-26 - 120 b + 3950 b^2 - 1500 b^3 + (250 + 7000 b - 1250 b^2) #1 
            + (125 + 5000 b) #1^2 + 3125 #1^3 &, 2] == 0, b]
```

> ```
> {{b -> -(1/15)}, {b -> 1/10}, {b -> 13/5}}
> ```

```
Solve[ ToRadicals[
         Root[-26 - 120 b + 3950 b^2 - 1500 b^3 + (250 + 7000 b - 1250 b^2) #1 
              + (125 + 5000 b) #1^2 + 3125 #1^3 &, 2]] == 0, b]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Comment: This is very useful, thanks. I get the same results as you do by using `Rationalize`. However, when I try to solve `sol = Solve[ Thread[ Re[ Eigenvalues[ matrix]] == 0], b]` Mathematica generates a warning saying that this equation cannot be solved. `NSolve` cannot solve it either. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @obareey It seems that quite similar issue I discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42781/solvetantheta-bsint-acost-theta-breaks-when-reals-is-added/42801#42801) (see also the links I gave there). Nonetheless such problems cannot be justified thoroughly as far as we don't access to the source code. I'll look on this monday if I haven't overlooked anything important (and possibly edit my answer), however it is obvoius that these eigenvalues form the complete set of them since the characteristic equation is of the third order and we can easily verify the solutions.

Comment: `ToRadicals` solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Values of `b` for which real parts of eigenvalues vanish in fact make the imaginary parts also vanish. One can show this as follows.

```
m = Rationalize[{{0.04 - 0.4 b, 0, 
     0.04 - 0.4 b}, {0, -0.08 - 1.2 b, -0.06 - 0.9 b}, {1.04 - 0.4 b, 
     2.08 - 0.8 b, 0}}];
cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[m, z];
```

Replace `z` by `x+I*y` where we will look for only real values of `x` and `y`.

```
ee = Expand[cp /. z -> x + I*y];
polys = ComplexExpand[{Re[ee], Im[ee]}]

(* Out[103]= {26/3125 + (24 b)/625 - (158 b^2)/125 + (12 b^3)/25 - (2 x)/
  25 - (56 b x)/25 + (2 b^2 x)/5 - x^2/25 - (8 b x^2)/5 - x^3 + y^2/
  25 + (8 b y^2)/5 + 3 x y^2, -((2 y)/25) - (56 b y)/25 + (2 b^2 y)/
  5 - (2 x y)/25 - (16 b x y)/5 - 3 x^2 y + y^3} *)
```

We want to find values of `b` such that these polynomials, and x, all vanish. And we only count solutions for which `y` is real.

```
Select[{x, y, b} /. 
  Solve[Join[{x}, polys] == 0, {x, y, b}], Im[#[[2]]] == 0 &]

(* {{0, 0, -(1/15)}, {0, 0, 1/10}, {0, 0, 13/5}} *)
```

So there are only three values of `b` that make the eigenvalue real parts vanish, and they make the imaginary parts vanish as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a very good way for finding $b$, I'm sure it will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to recognize that the product of the eigenvalues is equal to the determinant. Hence:

```
m = {{0.04 - 0.4 b, 0, 0.04 - 0.4 b}, {0, -0.08 - 1.2 b, -0.06 - 0.9 b}, 
     {1.04 - 0.4 b, 2.08 - 0.8 b, 0}};
Roots[Det[m] == 0, b]
```

Since the Det is a 3rd order polynomial, there are three zeros, which occur when

```
b == 2.6 || b == 0.1 || b == -0.0666667
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need that the real part of the eigenvalues to be 0. So, the determinant may not be 0.