# Unexpected result from FullSimplify

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

In the following simplification why doesn't Mathematica get a zero when asked to compute "Y-Z" eventually?

```
 a = 1 - 4 A Q^2; 
 b = (-972 + 648) A Q^2 + 54;
 c = 9 - 36 A Q^2; 

 Y = 12 Q/( 
 Sqrt[A] (  
   2 - (3 2^(1/3) a )/(Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c^3] + b  )^(1/3)  - ( 
       Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c^3] + b  )^(1/3)/( 3 2^(1/3) )     )   );

 Z = (4/A) + (3 2^(1/3) a )/(A (Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c^3] + b  )^(1/3) )  +  ( 
  Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c^3] + b  )^(1/3)/( 3 2^(1/3) A);

Q = Sqrt [ 3/(16 A)];
Y - Z // FullSimplify
(-9 + 4 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[1/A] Sqrt[A])/(2 A)
```

One can do the above calculation by hand and one would see that for the specific chosen value of $Q = \sqrt{3/16 A}$ one would get $Y =  Z = \frac{3}{A}$. Why doesn't Mathematica see this?

---

- And is there a way to get Mathematica to detect if there are other values of $Q$ where $Y = Z$? (..I found this one value special value of $Q$ by just staring at the equation for sometime...)

---

Rewriting the functions again.

$Y = \frac{12Q}{\sqrt{A}\sqrt{ 2 - \frac{3 (2^{1/3})a }{(\sqrt{b^2 - 4 c^3   } +  b  )^{1/3} }   - \frac{(\sqrt{b^2 - 4 c^3   } +  b  )^{1/3}  }{3 (2^{1/3})}    }    }$

$Z = \frac{1}{A} \left (4 +  \frac{(\sqrt{b^2 - 4 c^3   } +  b  )^{1/3}  }{3 (2^{1/3})}   + \frac{3 (2^{1/3})a }{(\sqrt{b^2 - 4 c^3   } +  b  )^{1/3} }\right ) $

at the chosen values of $Q = \sqrt{\frac{3}{16A} }$ one has $a = \frac{1}{4}$ and $b = - \frac{27}{4}$ and $b^2 - 4 c^3 = 0$. Also whenever I encounter $b^{1/3}$ I am writing that as $-3 \times 2^{-2/3}$. Substituting these into the above one gets $Y = Z = \frac{3}{A}$

Comment: You can try `$Assumptions = {A > 0};
Y - Z // FullSimplify` but it seems there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Getting $\frac{4 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{\frac{1}{A}} \sqrt{A}-9}{2 A}$ and with assuming A > 0 $\frac{4 \sqrt{3}-9}{2 A}$. No Zero.

Comment: @Phab But did you do the calculation by hand? Isn't it zero doing so?

Comment: @Anirbit Not on the first try. No time for a second so far.

Comment: @Phab I am quite confident that it is zero. (there are other cross-checks which it passes given the larger context fro where it comes) It would be great if you could kindly check again.

Comment: It is not zero. `{FullSimplify[Y //. {Q -> Sqrt[3/(16 A)], A -> 1}] // N, 
 FullSimplify[Z //. {Q -> Sqrt[3/(16 A)], A -> 1}] // N}` gives `{3.4641, 4.5}` so here is at least one value of A for which the two are not equal.

Comment: `FullSimplify[Y, Assumptions -> A > 0]` gives `(2 Sqrt[3])/A` and `FullSimplify[Z, Assumptions -> A > 0]` gives `9/(2 A)` for `Q = Sqrt[3/(16 A)]`, so your confidence that `Y - Z = 0` is misplaced.

Comment: @m_goldberg I am not sure whats going on here - do you agree or disagree with the intermediate steps that i have typed above? (below "Rewriting the functions..")

Comment: @bills Can you kindly see the intermediate steps that I have written above?

Comment: Using your formulas `Y /. A -> 1 // N // Chop`yields `3.4641` while `Z /. A -> 1 // N // Chop`yields `4.5`. These two figures are not equal.

Comment: @m_goldberg Do you see a difference between the two!?

Comment: "whenever I encounter b^1/3 I am writing that as `−3×2^(−2/3)`". That is incorrect. `b^(1/3)` is `-9/4`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't know what you mean. $(-3)^3 = - 27$ and $2^2 = 4$

Comment: You're right. I had some bad parentheses. Sorry

Comment: Shouldn't your expression `Y = 12 Q/(Sqrt[A] (...))` be `Y = 12 Q/Sqrt[A (...)]`?

Comment: This is closely related if not a duplicate: [Strange behavior of Reduce with a cubic equation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48529/strange-behavior-of-reduce-with-a-cubic-equation).

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that b^(1/3) has three roots. You are choosing the real root, `-(3/2^(2/3))`, while *Mathematica* is choosing, `(3 (-1)^(1/3))/2^(2/3)` which is complex. To get the result you want, rewrite your expressions for `Y` and `Z` like this:

```
Y =
  12 Q/
    Sqrt[A (2 - 
            (3 2^(1/3) a)/Surd[Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c^3] + b, 3] - 
            Surd[Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c^3] + b, 3]/(3 2^(1/3)))];

Z = (4/A) + (3 2^(1/3) a)/A /Surd[Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c^3] + b, 3] + 
   Surd[Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c^3] + b, 3]/(3 2^(1/3) A);
```

With the above you will get

```
FullSimplify[Y - Z, Assumptions -> A > 0]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```