# Quartic equation

Tags: equation-solving

After using Solve I am choosing the physical root of my equation and dealing further with this root. However, when I am changing parameters using Manipulate, I clearly see not smooth behaviour. Is there a way to cure it? I think, there should be a way of controlling the branch of the square root by adding $\pm i0$.

Comment: I ran into similar issues; basically, you have two choices: 1.  Compute the various cases by hand, and hard-program the correct values using `Piecewise`, or 2.  Insert `I*e` into the square-root expression appropriately, and take the `Limit` as `e->0`.  Mathematica will give a complicated answer but should result in correctly chosen branches.

Comment: Set `Quartics->False` so you get solutions as explicit `Root[...]` objects. Now have your code check for crossings and switch solutions as needed. This can be done by computing parameter values for which there are multiple roots (via a `Discriminant` computation, say).

Comment: I recommend that you include code for an example in your question.

Comment: I recommend to examine this answer [Finding parameters making real part of eigenvalues vanish](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46417/finding-parameters-making-real-part-of-eigenvalues-vanish/46426#46426) especially see the edit. In other words I recommend applying `ToRadicals` rather than working with simple `Root` objects.