# NSolve missing solutions in Mathematica 10

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, version-10

Running Mathematica 8.0.4 and 10.0.0 on a Windows 8.1 machine. Processed the same code with both kernels:

`k = .2; NSolve[Rationalize[2 r^2 - .2 r^(k + 2) - 1 == 0], r, Reals]`

The version 8 kernel returns two values as expected:

`{{r -> 0.742979}, {r -> 100000.}}`

The version 10 kernel returns only the first value by default. The second value doesn't appear as a solution until setting `WorkingPrecision` to at least 28.

The same behavior occurs for other values of `k`: the version 10 kernel needs massaging to return values the version 8 kernel finds by default. What would cause this?

Comment: Win7,10.0.0,give two solutions,0.742979 and 100000.

Comment: 100000 is not a solution. You are experiencing numerical issues.

Comment: This is closely related: [Issue with NSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391)

Comment: When using `VerifySolutions -> False`, it gives three, one wrong.

Comment: @Chenminqi did you get this result with a default installation or have you made configuration changes that would affect precision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wolfram support has confirmed to me that there is a known problem with NSolve in version 10. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 5):

The equation is numerically unstable. The second root is not valid at machine precision so is rejected. Higher precision is required to arrive at a valid second root. Use Solve to see exact solutions as root objects. Then use higher precision when converting root objects to numbers.

```
k = .2;
eqn = Rationalize[2 r^2 - .2 r^(k + 2) - 1 == 0];
sol = Solve[eqn, r, Reals]
```

> {{r -> Root[5 - 10 #1^10 + #1^11 &, 2]^5}, {r -> 
>          Root[5 - 10 #1^10 + #1^11 &, 3]^5}}

```
eqn /. sol // FullSimplify
```

> {True, True}

```
soln = sol // N[#, 30] &
```

> {{r -> 0.742978680869997548585535979527}, {r -> 
>      99999.9999749999999899999999927}}

```
eqn /. soln
```

> {True, True}

```
eqn[[1]] /. soln
```

> {0.*10^-30, 0.*10^-20}

Comment: `$MachinePrecision` has the same default value for both versions. If it is a matter of rejecting a solution at machine precision, then why doesn't that occur in version 8? I've also verified that the current version 9 CDF Player does not reject the second solution at default machine precision. The question remains as to why version 10 is behaving differently.

Comment: I don't know but in both V8 and V10 the `VerifySolutuons` option for `Solve` default is `Automatic` (presumably neither always `True` nor always `False`). Perhaps the "automatic" setting for V10 checked whereas V8 didn't.

Comment: Correction to above since you used `NSolve`. In V8 `NSolve` does not have a `VerifySolutions` option whereas in V10 it does. In V10 `VerifySolutuons` option for `NSolve` default is `Automatic`. Presumably it decided to check.