# NSolve finds real-valued results in version 9, but not in version 10

Tags: equation-solving, version-10, version-9, backslide

**UPDATE** `Reals` also was used in the code.

Actually, I tried the following simple piece of code.

```
P[T_, V_] := -(1/V^2) + T/V + (2 T)/(-1 + V)^3 + (4 T)/(-1 + V)^2;
NSolve[
  {
   D[P[T, V], {V, 1}] == 0,
   D[P[T, V], {V, 2}] == 0
   },
  {T, V},
  Reals
  ] // TableForm
```

And in **ver. 9**, the output was,

```
{
 {T -> -9.67712, V -> -2.35529},
 {T -> -5.12191, V -> -0.778707},
 {T -> 0.0943287, V -> 7.66613}
}
```

and in case of **ver. 10.3.1**, obtained,

```
{}
```

That is, these two versions apparently return different outputs.

Whats is the cause? **Is there any version dependency in Mathematica?**

Comment: @Shaqpad, you can even go further by typing `Quit` and entering it, this quits the kernel completely but leaves  the front end open.

Comment: Forgot about `Reals`. The shown outputs are for the case using `Reals`.

Comment: Ahhh... `Reals`! well yes, now the list is empty in 10.3.1 and not in v9, I can confirm there is a difference. Will delete old comments now obsolete.

Comment: The only relevant doc. found is [**this**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56194/36928)

Comment: Essentially the same issue as was reported [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102724/bug-wrong-results-from-nsolve-on-coupled-polynomials-workingprecision-automat). A workaround is to use `Method->"EndomorphismMatrix"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not a solution, more of an extended comment.

Clearly there are real solutions, the curves below **do** cross

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[{D[P[T, V], {V, 1}] == 0, 
   D[P[T, V], {V, 2}] == 0}], {V, -10, 10}, {T, -10, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

You can get the real-valued solutions version 9 gave via

```
Solve[{N@D[P[T, V], {V, 1}] == 0, 
  N@D[P[T, V], {V, 2}] == 0}, {T, V}, Reals]
```

> During evaluation of Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

```
(* {{T -> -9.67712, V -> -2.35529}, {T -> -5.12191, 
  V -> -0.778707}, {T -> 0.0943287, V -> 7.66613}} *)
```

You can also get these answers with `NSolve` (with a little more precision) by using the `Method` option

```
NSolve[
   {
     D[P[T, V], {V, 1}] == 0,
     D[P[T, V], {V, 2}] == 0
     },
   {T, V}
   , Reals, Method -> "UseSlicingHyperplanes"] 
(* {{T -> 0.0943287, V -> 7.66613}, {T -> -9.67712, 
  V -> -2.35529}, {T -> -5.12191, V -> -0.778707}} *)

{D[P[T, V], {V, 1}] , D[P[T, V], {V, 2}]} /. %
(* {{-1.12757*10^-17, 
  3.25261*10^-18}, {1.11022*10^-15, -1.9984*10^-15}, {3.55271*10^-15, 
  1.59872*10^-14}} *)
```

Why is this happening?  I don't know (hence the disclaimer at the top).  I know that the functions `NSolve` and the like are constantly undergoing development, and some of those very developers post here. They would be very interested in hearing about this I think.

Comment: Of course your answered my question; more than it deserves!

Answer (score 6):

You can use any of the alternative methods found here: [Methods for NSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40543/methods-for-nsolve/103029#103029)

For example:

```
NSolve[{D[P[T, V], {V, 1}] == 0, D[P[T, V], {V, 2}] == 0}, {T, V}, Reals,
 Method -> "Legacy"]
(*
  {{T -> 0.0943287, V -> 7.66613},
   {T -> -9.67712,  V -> -2.35529},
   {T -> -5.12191,  V -> -0.778707}}
*)
```

The other alternatives seem to work, too.  Except the default one.

This is cute, too (method `"Foo"`??):

```
NSolve[{D[P[T, V], {V, 1}] == 0, D[P[T, V], {V, 2}] == 0}, {T, V}, Reals,
 Method -> "Foo"]
(*
  {{T -> 0.0943287, V -> 7.66613}, {T -> -9.67712, 
    V -> -2.35529}, {T -> -5.12191, V -> -0.778707}}
*)
```

Comment: Now I'm just going to use random methods whenever I use `NSolve`, like `Method -> "JWalterWeatherman"`.  Is this big enough to be marked as a bug?

Comment: @JasonB [Daniel's comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104418/nsolve-finds-real-valued-results-in-version-9-but-not-in-version-10/104429?noredirect=1#comment283462_104418) says it's the same as [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102724), which was marked a bug.  -- BTW, `Method` settings are irregularly or loosely checked in some functions, with undefined settings falling through to a default.  In this case, the `Automatic` setting seems to be mishandled, but invalid settings get past the bug.