# NSolve and domain specifications

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I am using NSolve to find roots to a system of polynomials that describe some chemical reactions. However, I am seeing some odd behavior when I restrict the domain.

First, the basic setup:

```
c1 = 50.0; 
c2 = 1.5;
c3 = 0.4;
c4 = 0.5;
c5 = 8.0;
c6 = 3.2;
k1 = 3.7*10^-18;
k2 = 8.3*10^-9;
k3 = 8.7*10^-13;
k4 = 3.2*10^-7;
k5 = 8.6*10^-3;
f1 = 1/2*(c1-c2+c3+2*c4-c5+c6-x1-2*x2-x3+x4+(x3*x4)/(k5*x1));
f2 = 1/(2*k5*x1)*(3*k5*c6*x1-k5*c1*x1+2*k5*c4*x1+k5*c3*x1-k5*c2*x1-k5*c5*x1+k5*x1^2-2*k5*x1*x2-k5*x1*x3+k5*x1*x4-x3*x4);
eqs={
     f1*f2 - k1*x1^2 == 0,
     f1*x3 - k2*x2*x1 == 0,
     f1*(c6 - x3 - x2 - (x3*x4)/(k5*x1)) - k3*x1*x3 == 0,
     f2*(c5 - x4 - (x3*x4)/(k5*x1)) - k4*x1*x4 == 0
    };
NSolve[eqs,{x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

This returns 32 complex roots. However, I know at the onset that there is at least one real-valued root, and exactly one real root with all four variables greater than zero. So, I try it again and use the specification suggested in the documentation to search for Reals only.

```
NSolve[eqs, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Reals]
```

This, however, returns {} for no solutions. However, while playing around with the options I accidentally used "Real" instead of "Reals":

```
NSolve[eqs, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Real]
```

Now, I receive a warning:

```
NSolve::bdomv: Warning: Real is not a valid domain specification. Assuming it is a variable to eliminate. >>
```

But I also get 8 real roots! Interestingly, these are the same roots I find if I run the original calculation at any WorkingPrecision that is not MachinePrecision...

```
NSolve[eqs, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision]
NSolve[eqs, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, WorkingPrecision->2]
NSolve[eqs, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, WorkingPrecision->20]
```

Lastly, I also tried restricting the domain to positive reals. This fails to return any result. If I combine this with a finite WorkingPrecision I get the correct root. If I instead specify "Reals" I get nothing, and I use "Real" I get warnings about the domain as well as infinite solutions, but the same root as above when I used Working Precision.

```
NSolve[Catenate[{eqs, {x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0}}], {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
NSolve[Catenate[{eqs, {x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0}}], {x1, x2, x3, x4}, WorkingPrecision -> 8]
NSolve[Catenate[{eqs, {x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0}}], {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Reals]
NSolve[Catenate[{eqs, {x1 > 0, x2 > 0, x3 > 0, x4 > 0}}], {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Real]

{}
{{x1 -> 49.4605, x2 -> 0.00100605, x3 -> 0.511294, x4 -> 2.21332}, {x1 -> 53.0999, x2 -> 4.30992*10^-13, x3 -> 0.000114669, x4 -> 7.99797}}
{}
NSolve::bdomv: Warning: Real is not a valid domain specification. Assuming it is a variable to eliminate. >>
NSolve::infsolns: Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1. Returning intersection of solutions with -((41688 x1)/65167)-(153968 x2)/195501+(153196 x3)/195501+(185938 x4)/195501+(38650 System`NSolveDump`Y$31197[1])/65167 == 1. >>
{{x1 -> 49.4605, x2 -> 0.00100591, x3 -> 0.511294, x4 -> 2.21332}}
```

Anyone have insight into these behaviors?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a case of ill conditioning of the input system. If I redo using exact input and set `NSolve` to work on high precision then I get a plausible outcome.

```
c1 = 50;
c2 = 3/2;
c3 = 2/5;
c4 = 1/2;
c5 = 8;
c6 = 16/5;
k1 = 37*10^(-17);
k2 = 83*10^(-8);
k3 = 87*10^(-12);
k4 = 32*10^(-6);
k5 = 86*10^(-32);
eqs = {f1*f2 - k1*x1^2, f1*x3 - k2*x2*x1, 
   f1*(c6 - x3 - x2 - (x3*x4)/(k5*x1)) - k3*x1*x3, 
   f2*(c5 - x4 - (x3*x4)/(k5*x1)) - k4*x1*x4};
solns = N[
  NSolve[eqs, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix", 
   WorkingPrecision -> 200]]

(* Out[915]= {{x1 -> 54.8004248857, x2 -> -0.0000977553043262, 
  x3 -> -1.70022938028, 
  x4 -> -2.2175062235*10^-28}, {x1 -> 53.0993625312, 
  x2 -> -8.87278874951*10^-12, x3 -> 0.000637468817923, 
  x4 -> 5.73084681075*10^-25}, {x1 -> 51.7000000017, 
  x2 -> 3.33952465735*10^-15, x3 -> -8.42954955495*10^-20, 
  x4 -> -1.68785294015*10^-9}, {x1 -> 46.9000236518, 
  x2 -> -4.79997634819, x3 -> -0.0000236518142965, 
  x4 -> -1.364259666*10^-23}, {x1 -> 53.0973683194, 
  x2 -> 2.32767391416*10^-37, x3 -> 3.04591909329*10^-29, 
  x4 -> 4.79736831936}, {x1 -> 50.0008781357, 
  x2 -> 2.05348705909*10^-33, x3 -> 8.0900808571*10^-29, 
  x4 -> 1.70087813781}, {x1 -> 54.8000177886, x2 -> 3.10212897782, 
  x3 -> -7.90424004255, 
  x4 -> -4.76989717362*10^-29}, {x1 -> 2.09855075596*10^-11, 
  x2 -> -51.7, x3 -> -8.85456356826*10^-18, 
  x4 -> -1.11898203258*10^-22}} *)
```

Check residuals:

```
eqs /. solns

(* Out[916]= {{1.45782281955*10^-18, -5.83359947449*10^-15, \
-1.06351826451*10^-14, -7.54753185026*10^-19}, {1.25900746755*10^-15, \
-4.71927742874*10^-19, 
  3.55398404018*10^-15, -9.73773799727*10^-28}, \
{-7.83975673111*10^-15, 9.62964972194*10^-35, 3.79152709445*10^-28, 
  2.21357836972*10^-14}, {-5.8353686176*10^-15, 
  0., -1.72569257779*10^-15, 
  1.25720897678*10^-28}, {4.9846880603*10^-15, 
  4.90188927228*10^-44, -1.40705350532*10^-37, \
-1.61849700309*10^-15}, {6.95980079332*10^-19, 6.41188041986*10^-44, 
  4.67805560848*10^-25, 
  9.91090889912*10^-15}, {9.35073564361*10^-20, -2.37330771355*10^-14,
   6.3636526536*10^-18, 
  1.10569373992*10^-22}, {4.59635768258*10^-13, -1.97215226305*10^-31,
   1.61661234308*10^-38, -2.11965757437*10^-13}} *)
```

A couple of them are all positive.

```
Select[{x1, x2, x3, x4} /. solns, 
 Apply[And, Thread[# >= 0]] &]

(* Out[931]= {{53.0973683194, 2.32767391416*10^-37, 3.04591909329*10^-29,
   4.79736831936}, {50.0008781357, 2.05348705909*10^-33, 
  8.0900808571*10^-29, 1.70087813781}} *)
```

There may be other ways to do this. I had but little luck using `FindMinimum` on the sum of squares but there might be option settings that would make that work reasonably well.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of [NSolve finds real-valued results in version 9, but not in version 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104418/nsolve-finds-real-valued-results-in-version-9-but-not-in-version-10/104429#104429),
in which you can use any of the `Method` settings from [Methods for NSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40543/methods-for-nsolve/103029#103029)

```
"EndomorphismMatrix"
"CompanionMatrix"
"Legacy"
"Aberth"
"JenkinsTraub"
```

or even a nonexistent method `"Foo"`:

```
NSolve[eqs, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Reals, Method -> "Foo"]
(*
  {{x1 -> 23.2915, x2 -> -28.505, x3 -> 55.2247, x4 -> -0.0852683},
   {x1 -> 46.3516, x2 -> -5.36977, x3 -> 9.01972, x4 -> -0.0198153},
   {x1 -> 56.3754, x2 -> -0.000327403, x3 -> -3.16593, x4 -> -1.46634},
   {x1 -> 54.9, x2 -> 3.2, x3 -> -1.80018*10^-7, x4 -> -6.26944*10^-10},
   {x1 -> 52.6254, x2 -> 0.0121417, x3 -> -2.70055, x4 -> -0.976273},
   {x1 -> 52.2298, x2 -> -0.0000285978, x3 -> 0.928352, x4 -> 2.62754},
   {x1 -> 49.4605, x2 -> 0.00100605, x3 -> 0.511294, x4 -> 2.21332},
   {x1 -> 53.0999, x2 -> 4.30992*10^-13, x3 -> 0.000114669, x4 -> 7.99797}}
*)
```