# Duplicate solutions in NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, bugs

In v11.3 `NSolve` returns a bunch of redundant solutions for the following set of six equations:

```
eqns={
  0 == -0.07 s1 + 0.3 (0.75 i1 + s1) (1 - 0.05 (i1 + i2 + i3 + s1 + s2 + s3)),
  0 == -0.28 i1,
  0 == -0.07 s2 - 0.5 i1 s2 - 0.5 i2 s2 - 0.5 i3 s2 + 0.8 (0.75 i2 + s2) (1 - 0.05 (i1 + i2 + i3 + s1 + s2 + s3)), 
  0 == -0.28 i2 + 0.5 i1 s2 + 0.5 i2 s2 + 0.5 i3 s2,
  0 == -0.07 s3 - 0.4 i1 s3 - 0.4 i2 s3 - 0.4 i3 s3 + 0.7 (0.75 i3 + s3) (1 - 0.05 (i1 + i2 + i3 + s1 + s2 + s3)), 
  0 == -0.28 i3 + 0.4 i1 s3 + 0.4 i2 s3 + 0.4 i3 s3};

unks={s1, i1, s2, i2, s3, i3};

eq = NSolve[eqns, unks];
Length[eq]
(* 30 *)
```

For example, `{s1 -> 0, i1 -> 0, s2 -> 18.25, i2 -> 0, s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}` shows up in `eq` twice, `{s1 -> 0, i1 -> 0, s2 -> 0, i2 -> 0, s3 -> 18., i3 -> 0}` shows up four times, etc.

In v11.2, `NSolve` returns twelve unique solutions, as does `Solve` in v11.3:

```
eq = Solve[eqns, unks];
Length[eq]
(* 12 *)
```

Giving `NSolve` a `Method` such as `"EndomorphismMatrix"`, `"CompanionMatrix"`, `"Legacy"`, `"Aberth"`, `"JenkinsTraub"` as discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103029/6358) results in the proper set of twelve solutions.  **Edit:** Even non-existent methods give twelve.  However `Method->"Homotopy"` gives 30.

Does v11.3 use a new `Method` for `NSolve` that produces  this seeming bug?  What would the best workaround be?

**Edit:**

`$Version` gives "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" so something must have changed since "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 22, 2018)" in @MichaelE2's comment.

I've reported it to WRI.

BTW, this example surfaced in a general function I wrote, so any work-around should be generally applicable not just deal with this particular example.

Comment: I get only 12 in V11.3 MacOS: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FPM3x.png

Comment: If the system is always polynomial, consider `Method -> "Legacy"`. Since `NSolve` started as a polynomial solver, maybe you're not losing anything.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good idea but unfortunately the system isn't necessarily polynomial.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That `Trace` yields `{}`.  I suppose I'll use the non-existent `Method->"Foo"` as a hack.

Comment: That's  what I figured.  Oh, well.  It's certainly a backslide. I suppose it should be called a bug.

Comment: (1) The sparse homotopy method can overcount the actual number and fail to recognize that several solutions are actually the same. Offhand I do not recall if there is a good way to detect multiplicity vs overcount, other than maybe by difficulty of obtaining convergence for solutions with multiplicity (which of course makes matters difficult, since they might not look the same).

Comment: (2) I believe this method is only implemented in machine precision, hence using anything else, even low arbitrary precision, will cause a different method to be used. (3) Likewise, invoking a nonexistent method will cause the endomorphism matrix method to be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a non-existent `Method->"Foo"` as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104429/6358) fixes the problem, as does `Method->"EndomorphismMatrix"`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment.  Actually, the answers only appear to be the same.  For instance, `eq[[6]]` and `eq[[7]]` actually are

```
{{s1 -> 0, i1 -> 0, s2 -> 18.249999999999982`, i2 -> 0, s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}}
{{s1 -> 0, i1 -> 0, s2 -> 18.249999999988777`, i2 -> 0, s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}}
```

More generally, `Union@eq` does not reduce the number of solutions, indicating that there are small differences among them.  Perhaps, `NSolve` performs its analysis on the equations in various orders, yielding solutions that differ in some cases only by roundoff.

Incidentally,

```
Solve[Rationalize[eqns, 0], unks]
```

gives the twelve desired solutions exactly.

Comment: Yes this issue seems particular to `NSolve`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) the equations

```
eqns = {0 == -0.07 s1 + 
       0.3 (0.75 i1 + s1) (1 - 0.05 (i1 + i2 + i3 + s1 + s2 + s3)), 
     0 == -0.28 i1, 
     0 == -0.07 s2 - 0.5 i1 s2 - 0.5 i2 s2 - 0.5 i3 s2 + 
       0.8 (0.75 i2 + s2) (1 - 0.05 (i1 + i2 + i3 + s1 + s2 + s3)), 
     0 == -0.28 i2 + 0.5 i1 s2 + 0.5 i2 s2 + 0.5 i3 s2, 
     0 == -0.07 s3 - 0.4 i1 s3 - 0.4 i2 s3 - 0.4 i3 s3 + 
       0.7 (0.75 i3 + s3) (1 - 0.05 (i1 + i2 + i3 + s1 + s2 + s3)), 
     0 == -0.28 i3 + 0.4 i1 s3 + 0.4 i2 s3 + 0.4 i3 s3} // Rationalize // 
   Simplify;

unks = {s1, i1, s2, i2, s3, i3};
```

Use arbitrary precision by setting the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html)

```
eq = NSolve[eqns, unks, WorkingPrecision -> 7]

(* {{i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, s2 -> -62.9200 - 11.5510 I, i2 -> -15.1800 + 38.4020 I, 
  s3 -> 79.3500 + 14.4388 I, i3 -> 15.2500 - 38.7566 I}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, 
  s2 -> -62.9200 + 11.5510 I, i2 -> -15.1800 - 38.4020 I, 
  s3 -> 79.3500 - 14.4388 I, i3 -> 15.2500 + 38.7566 I}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, 
  s2 -> 18.25000, i2 -> 0, s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, s2 -> 0, 
  i2 -> 0, s3 -> 18.00000, i3 -> 0}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 14.21852, s2 -> 0, 
  i2 -> 0, s3 -> 0.700000, i3 -> 0.4148148}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 15.33333, 
  s2 -> 0, i2 -> 0, s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, s2 -> 0, i2 -> 0, 
  s3 -> 0.700000, i3 -> 9.41499}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 14.30667, s2 -> 0.560000, 
  i2 -> 0.4666667, s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, s2 -> 0.560000, 
  i2 -> 10.60545, s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, s2 -> 0, i2 -> 0, 
  s3 -> 0.700000, i3 -> -1.714995}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, s2 -> 0.560000, 
  i2 -> -1.245448, s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}, {i1 -> 0, s1 -> 0, s2 -> 0, i2 -> 0, 
  s3 -> 0, i3 -> 0}} *)
```

Verifying solutions

```
And @@ (eqns /. eq // Flatten)

(* True *)
```

[`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) returned the expected 12 solutions

```
Length[eq]

(* 12 *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  It seems that the `WorkingPrecision->7` alone does the trick; `Rationalize` alone results in 31 solutions.

Comment: @ChrisK You probably want `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` (~ 15.95) or higher, unless that doesn't work.  Not sure why Bob chose `7`, which is less than single-precision.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - `WorkingPrecision -> 7]` was chosen to show that even low-precision arbitrary-precision is better than machine precision. If you remove the `WorkingPrecision` option, `And @@ (eqns /. eq // Flatten)` evaluates to `False`, i.e., the results are not sufficiently precise to demonstrably satisfy the equations. Any specified `WorkingPrecision` above `7` (including `$MachinePrecision`) is clearly more precise; however, it will clutter the output.

Comment: Thanks. But I'd assert that the machine precision calculations are more precise than the `WorkingPrecision -> 7` ones.  The reason you get `True` is that the rounding error estimate is taken into consideration, given that the initial numbers are accurate to only 7 digits. The maximum of the residual errors (i.e. the right-hand sides of the OP's `eqns`) at machine precision is `2.37442*10^-9`, whereas for 7 digits, *Mathematica* estimates a bound of `3.16306` and the actual error is `0.655472`, which results in an arbtrary-precision zero of about ```0``-0.5```.