# Problem in finding the numerical maximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to find the numerical maxima of the function

$$i(s)=\bigg[ \frac{\sin{50\pi (\cos s+1)}}{\sin{10\pi (\cos s+1)}} \bigg] ^2$$

Or in the mathematica input form:

```
i[s_] := (Sin[50 \[Pi] (Cos[s] + 1)]/Sin[10 \[Pi] (Cos[s] + 1)])^2
```

Whose plot looks like this:

[image: Ignore the axes labels!]

But Mathematica cannot find its maxima. I've tried

```
NMaximize[i[s], s]
```

Which gives a single local maximum (the help file said that this could happen for some nonlinear functions).

```
Table[FindMaximum[i[s],{s,x Degree}],{x,0,90}]
```

Returned some (not all) of the peaks, but mostly random points that are not even local maxima.

```
NSolve[i'[s]==0,s]
```

Returned some (still, not all) of the local maxima, but all the shark peaks were omitted.

So how can I get all the peaks with Mathematica? Notice that the peak occurs for every four local maxima. Thanks!

Comment: `NSolve[Simplify[i'[s]] == 0 && 0 <= s <= 2 \[Pi], s]` finds all of the stationary points, which you could then develop into a full solution to your problem.

Comment: @AlexSu Thank for you the accept.  I discovered another post where the `NSolve` issue is solved and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** The problem with `NSolve` is addressed in [Issue with NSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391)

The problem with obtaining the large peaks is that they occur where the denominator is zero.  The function turns out to have a finite limit at those places, so the discontinuity is removable.  Since removing it is desired, I would recommend setting the problem up, so that there is no discontinuity.  [`TrigExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrigExpand.html) can help.

```
expr = (Sin[50 π (Cos[s] + 1)]/Sin[10 π (Cos[s] + 1)])^2;
i = expr // TrigExpand // Simplify
(* (1 + 2 Cos[20 π Cos[s]] + 2 Cos[40 π Cos[s]])^2 *)
```

One could carry this further, if desired, to write the problem as a polynomial in `Cos[20 π Cos[s]]` via the double-angle formula.  *Mathematica* sometimes figures out for itself how to do it.  The reason is that polynomials are easier to deal with.

**Solution 1**

I suppose if one had the local maxima over a period, then in a sense one knows all the local maxima.  It's perhaps not so clear that the period is π instead of 2 π.

```
i - (i /. s -> s + Pi) // Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

The easiest and possibly fastest way to get the maxima numerically is via `NDSolve` and [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html).  We start the integration a little before zero so that `WhenEvent` can capture the maximum at the origin.

```
{sol1} = N@
   Last@Reap[
     NDSolve[{f'[s] == D[i, s], f[-0.01] == (i /. s -> -0.01), 
       WhenEvent[f'[s] < 0, Sow[s]]}, f, {s, -0.01, Pi - 0.0001}]];

Plot[i, {s, -0.01, Pi},
 GridLines -> {sol1, None}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Red], AspectRatio -> 1/10, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Solution 2**

`Solve` (or `Reduce`) of course can solve the problem exactly, although a little slowly, as others have shown.  Here is my approach.  It returns roots with multiplicity, so I delete the duplicates.

```
sol2 = DeleteDuplicates[s /. Solve[D[i, s] == 0 && i > 0 && 0 <= s < Pi, s]]
```

**Solution 3**

One can also use `NSolve` instead of `Solve` as follows:

```
sol3 = s /. NSolve[D[i, s] == 0 && i > 0 && 0 <= s < Pi, s]
```

It will be fairly fast and highly accurate.

Warning (updated): If I extend the domain to `0 <= s < 2 Pi`, `NSolve` omits the solution at `Pi`.  At explanation can be found in Artes' answer which is linked above.  The way to get all the solution is to explicitly specify the domain `Complexes`:

```
sol3b = s /. NSolve[D[i, s] == 0 && i > 0 && 0 <= s <= 2 Pi, s, Complexes]
```

However, this way takes several seconds, just about as long as `Solve` (which gives exact results).  A faster way to use `NSolve` to get all the solutions is to solve each factor separately:

```
sol3c = s /. NSolve[Power @@ ## == 0 && i > 0 && 0 <= s <= 2 Pi, s] & /@ 
   FactorList[D[i, s]] // DeleteDuplicates
```

For this problem `NSolve` would be my choice were it not for this difficulty; if highly accurate solutions are desired, then I would recommend one of these two updated methods, `sol3b` or `sol3c`.  A further consideration is that `NSolve` is limited in the types of equations it can handle.  The `NDSolve` approach in solution 1 works more generally.  And I like `NDSolve`.  These were my considerations behind the claim above that it's "easiest."

Answer (score 6):

```
f = (Sin[50 Pi (Cos[#] + 1)]/Sin[10 Pi (Cos[#] + 1)])^2 &;

Plot[f[s], {s, 0, 1},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshFunctions -> {ConditionalExpression[f'[#], f''[#] < 0 && f[#] > 0] &},
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red}]
```

[image]

```
table = Table[f[s], {s, 0., 1, 0.0001}];

peaks = FindPeaks[table, 1];

ygrid = Round[Map[Last, peaks], 0.0001] // Union
```

> {1., 1.5625, 25.}

```
ListPlot[{table, peaks},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 Filling -> {2 -> -1},
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick],
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0}, {5000, 0.5}, {10000, 1}}, Automatic},
 GridLines -> {{0, 5000, 10000}, ygrid},
 Joined -> {True, False},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, PointSize[0.01]}},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a little help, Mathematica can give you the exact positions of all maxima. Consider

```
f[s_] := Sin[50 \[Pi] (Cos[s] + 1)]/Sin[10 \[Pi] (Cos[s] + 1)]
```

Since all minima of this function are negative and all maxima are positive, the maxima of i(s) correspond to the extreme values of f(s). Therefore, they are the zeroes of

```
D[f[s], s] // Simplify
```

(*  80 [Pi] (3 Cos[10 [Pi] Cos[s]] + 2 Cos[30 [Pi] Cos[s]]) Sin[s] Sin[10 [Pi] Cos[s]]  *)

Hence the maxima of i(s) are at the positions

```
Solve[% == 0 && 0 <= s <= \[Pi]/2, s]
```

(* long output, omitted *)

Therefore, the maxima of i(s) are:

```
Table[{z[[1, 2]], Limit[i[s], z[[1]]]}, {z, %}]
```

(* long output, omitted *)

So the extrema you are looking for are

```
Select[%, #[[2]] == 25 &]
```

(*  {{0, 25}, {0, 25}, {0, 25}, {[Pi]/3, 25}, {[Pi]/2, 25}, {ArcCos[1/10], 
  25}, {ArcCos[1/5], 25}, {ArcCos[3/10], 25}, {ArcCos[2/5], 25}, {ArcCos[3/5],
   25}, {ArcCos[7/10], 25}, {ArcCos[4/5], 25}, {ArcCos[9/10], 25}}  *)

Answer (score 1):

You can employ the standard procedure to find the maxima of i[s], 
i.e. look for s such that i'[s]==0 and i''[s] < 0

The function in question is

```
i[s_] := (Sin[50 \[Pi] (Cos[s] + 1)]/Sin[10 \[Pi] (Cos[s] + 1)])^2
```

Plot it to get a first impression

```
Plot[{1, i[s], i'[s], i''[s]}, {s, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 30}]

(* picture not shown here *)
```

Now we apply reduce to the generic conditions for the maximum

```
r = Reduce[(i'[s] == 0) && (i''[s] < 0)] /. C[1] -> n;
Short[r, 2]
```

$(n\in \text{Integers}\&\&(\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle )\&\&\text{Sin}[s]==0)\left\|\left(n\in \text{Integers}\&\&\left(\left(\text{Sin}[s]\in \text{Reals}\&\&\text{Sin}[s]\neq 0\&\&\text{Cos}[s]==\frac{-5 \pi +n \pi +\text{ArcTan}\left[\text{Root}\left[5-22 \text{$\#$1}^2+5 \text{$\#$1}^4\&,1\right]\right]}{5 \pi }\right)\left\|\left(\text{Sin}[s]\in \text{Reals}\&\&\text{Sin}[s]\neq 0\&\&\text{Cos}[s]==\frac{1}{20} (-21+4 n)\right)\right\|(\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle )\|(\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle )\|(\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle )\|\left(\text{Sin}[s]\in \text{Reals}\&\&\text{Sin}[s]\neq 0\&\&\text{Cos}[s]==\frac{-5 \pi +n \pi +\text{ArcTan}\left[\text{Root}\left[5-22 \text{$\#$1}^2+5 \text{$\#$1}^4\&,4\right]\right]}{5 \pi }\right)\right)\right)\right.$

A rather long expression results. Prominent feature is the appearance of the roots of two polynomials

```
Table[ArcTan[Root[1 - 10 #1^2 + 5 #1^4 &, k]], {k, 1, 4}] // N

(* Out[5]= {-0.942478, -0.314159, 0.314159, 0.942478} *)

Table[ArcTan[Root[5 - 22 #1^2 + 5 #1^4 &, k]], {k, 1, 4}] // N

(* Out[6]= {-1.11493, -0.455869, 0.455869, 1.11493} *)
```

As an example of how to proceed let us pick just one component

```
r2 = r[[2, 2, 2]]

(* Out[7]= Sin[s] \[Element] Reals && Sin[s] != 0 && Cos[s] == 1/20 (-21 + 4 n) *)
```

and Solve it for s, removing the trivial shift by a multiple of 2 Pi

```
r3 = Solve[r2, s] /. C[1] -> 0

(* Out[10]= {{s -> -ArcCos[-(21/20) + n/5]}, {s -> ArcCos[-(21/20) + n/5]}, {s -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(41 - 4 n)/(-1 + 4 n)]], 
    1/4 < n < 41/4]}, {s -> 
   ConditionalExpression[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(41 - 4 n)/(-1 + 4 n)]], 
    1/4 < n < 41/4]}} *)
```

In order to obtain all typical values for this component we need to go to n = 11.
In fact

```
s1 = s /. Table[r3, {n, 0, 11}] // N;
```

Now we select the real roots and remove multiple roots to get

```
s2 = Union[Select[Round[Flatten[s1], 10^(-5)], (# \[Element] Reals) && (# > 0) &]] //
  N

(* Out[62]= {0.31756, 0.72273, 0.98843, 1.21323, 1.42023, 1.62082, 1.82348, 2.03756, \
2.27838, 2.58678} *)
```

These all give maximum = 1:

```
i[s2]

(* Out[63]= {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
```

I leave it to the attentive and patient reader, to explore the other solutions along the same lines.

Regards,
Wolfgang