# Solve returns a solution set, but NSolve returns an empty set

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following set of equations and paramters (ODE):

```
u4 = 1 - u1 - u2 - u3 - u6;

d1 = p1 - k1*u2*u5 - k3*u1*u5 - k4*u3*u5 - k5*u5*p4*u4 - p4*k6*u1*u5*u6;
d2 = k1*u2*u5 - k2*u1*p2 - k3*u1*u5 - p4*k6*u1*u5*u6;
d3 = -k1*u2*u5 + k2*u1*p2 + k5*u5*p4*u4 + 2*p4*k6*u1*u5*u6 - k7*(u2 - u6)*p3;
d4 = k3*u1*u5 - k4*u3*u5 ;
d5 = -k6*p4*u1*u5*u6 + k7*(u2 - u6)*p3;

k1 = 1;
k2 = 500;
k3 = 1/10;
k4 = 1/10;
k5 = 1/10;
k6 = 10;
k7 = 1;
p1 = 2/100;
p4 = 1;
p2 = p1;
p3 = 0;
p2 = p1/100;
```

When I try and solve these equations analytically I get a set of solutions, but when I try to do this numerically, I get an empty set:

```
Solve[{d1==0,d2==0,d3==0,d4==0,d5==0},{u1,u2,u3,u5,u6},Reals];
```

returns a set of solutions while

```
NSolve[{d1==0,d2==0,d3==0,d4==0,d5==0},{u1,u2,u3,u5,u6},Reals];
```

returns `{}`.

Why is that so?

Comment: I am getting a solution set in V11.0 with `NSolve`.

Comment: `Solve` and `NSolve` are not equivalent functions providing equivalent sets of solutions.  You can find a detailed discussion of this issue here  [Issue with NSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391). Nonetheless `NSolve` can also find a solution: `NSolve[{d1 == 0, d2 == 0, d3 == 0, d4 == 0, d5 == 0}~Join~
  Thread[-1 <= Re[#] <= 1 &@{u1, u2, u3, u5, u6}], {u1, u2, u3, u5, 
  u6}]`.  One can get rid off big imaginary parts of solutions setting `WorkingPrecision -> 10`.

Comment: hmm.. I'm running this on V10.2, I'll restart it and we'll see what happens

Comment: @Artes I'm not sure I understand your final comment. I'm specifying in my command to solve over the reals.

Comment: Just read [Issue with NSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391).  I meant to evaluate: `NSolve[{d1 == 0, d2 == 0, d3 == 0, d4 == 0, d5 == 0}~Join~
  Thread[-1 <= Re[#] <= 1 &@{u1, u2, u3, u5, u6}], {u1, u2, u3, u5, 
  u6}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]`. It apears there is some problem with implementation of  `NSolve`, especially related to usage of domains.