# Backslide in NSolve in V11.1?

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, special-functions, backslide

**Bug introduced in 11.1.0 and persisting through 11.1.1**

---

In V11.1,

```
NSolve[BesselJ[0, x] == 0 && 0 < x < 20, x]
```

returns no solutions:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But in V11.0 (and earlier), it returns all solutions:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there anyway to get `NSolve` to solve this equation in V11.1?

(Interestingly, `Solve[BesselJ[0, x] == 0 && 0 < x < 20, x]` works in both, but I was particularly interested `NSolve`, since I was wanting to compare it with other numerical methods.)

Comment: It's weird that this only happens for special functions; with elementary functions like the trigonometric functions, `NSolve[]` works fine.

Comment: There were also similar problems in NSolve dealing with elementary functions, see e.g. this post [Issue with NSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391).

Comment: `NSolve[BesselJ[0, x] == 0 && 0 < x < 20, x, Abracadabra] // Quiet`  :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a bug in V11.1. As a workaround, you can put the following in your init.m file.

```
Reduce`RealTNRoots;
nonElementaryQ[f_] := Module[{x}, !ListQ[Simplify`FunctionSingularities[f[x], x, "ELEM"]]]
System`TRootsDump`NIntervalRoots[f_?nonElementaryQ, ii_, prec_] := $Failed
```

This will disable the offending code for non-elementary functions.

```
In[4]:= NSolve[BesselJ[0, x] == 0 && 0 < x < 20, x]
Out[4]= {{x -> 2.40483}, {x -> 5.52008}, {x -> 8.65373}, {x -> 11.7915},
>    {x -> 14.9309}, {x -> 18.0711}}
```

Answer (score 14):

> Is there anyway to get NSolve to solve this equation in V11.1?

Adding `Complexes` makes it work

```
    NSolve[BesselJ[0, x] == 0 && 0 < x < 20, x, Complexes]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: it works in 11.1

Comment: Thanks! `NSolve[BesselJ[0, x] == 0 && 0 < Re[x] < 20, x]` and `NSolve[BesselJ[0, x] == 0 && 0 < Re[x] < 20 && Im[x] == 0, x]` also work (suggested by your answer).  I don't understand the reason for the change, since it breaks previous code.

Comment: Works for other special functions, too.  But `NSolve[Zeta[x] - 2 == 0 && 0 < Re@x < 2 && Im[x] == 0, x]` takes 4.5 sec and `NSolve[Zeta[x] - 2 == 0 && 1 < x < 2, x, Complexes]` takes 18.5 sec.; `NSolve[-2 + Zeta[x] == 0 && 1 < Re[x] < 2, x]` fails (but that's not surprising -- I was more surprised it worked on the Bessel funciton).