# What's going on with this system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

The following system of equations has $6$ solutions $(ct=8,8,8,8,7,9)$ but *Mathematica* doesn't give any solution:

```
NSolve[{ Sqrt[EAx^2 + 0.0625 EAy^2] (EBx) + (EAx) Sqrt[
              EBx^2 + 0.0625 EBy^2] == 0, 
         0.25 Sqrt[EAx^2 + 0.0625 EAy^2] EBy + 0.25 EAy Sqrt[EBx^2 + 0.0625 EBy^2] == 0, 
         EAy - EBy == 0, 
         -1 + 4 EAx^2 + EAy^2 == 0, 
         -1 + 4 EBx^2 + EBy^2 == 0,
         -8 + ct + EAx - EBx == 0},
       {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 13]
```

> ```
>  NSolve::infsolns: Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1.
>  Returning intersection of solutions with 
>   (38650 ct)/65167-(41688 EAx)/65167-(153968 EAy)/195501+(185938 
>    EBx)/195501+(153196 EBy)/195501 == 1. >>
>
>  {}
> ```

Why ?

Comment: You have 6 equations for 5 variables there.

Comment: Are you sure all the equations are correct? If you name the list of equations `eqs`, you can even `Rationalize` them, and check with exact `Solve`. But `Solve[Rationalize[eqs] /. ct -> 8, {EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}, Reals]` returns `{}`, so there are actually no solutions for this. Since you claim that you know that solutions exist for `ct == 8`, can you give the values of the other variables that solve the equations?

Comment: `Solve[{Sqrt[EAx^2 + 1/16 EAy^2] (EBx) + (EAx) Sqrt[
      EBx^2 + 1/16 EBy^2] == 0, 
  1/4 Sqrt[EAx^2 + 1/16 EAy^2] EBy + 
    1/4 EAy Sqrt[EBx^2 + 1/16 EBy^2] == 0, 
  EAy - EBy == 0, -1 + 4 EAx^2 + EAy^2 == 0, -1 + 4 EBx^2 + EBy^2 == 
   0, -8 + ct + EAx - EBx == 0, ct \[Element] Reals}, {ct, EAx, EAy, 
  EBx, EBy}]`

Comment: @KraZug There are 6 equations but the system is not overdetermined since the equations are not independent.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer There are actually `6`  solutions where `ct` is real, but another variables are not neccessarily real. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since one expects an appropriate number of solutions it is reasonable to play with `Solve` or `Reduce` rather than with `NSolve`, and such a conclusion is quite obvious for experienced users, but **by no means there is a direct hint** in documentation pages. There is a number of various issues related to distinction between **symbolic** and **numeric** capabilities of the system, I would recommend e.g. these posts to read carefully:
[Issue with NSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32388/issue-with-nsolve/32391#32391) as well as [Backslide in NSolve in V11.1?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143824/backslide-in-nsolve-in-v11-1). Basically one could belive there should be **one to one correspondence** between `Solve` and `NSolve` results, however implementation reality appears to be slightly different, the former function is much more sophisticated and has had more updates than the latter and this is why sometimes they provide inequivalent results besides issues qualified as simple bugs.  Moreover, even a specific usage of `Solve` sometimes may seem quite unreasonable for an unexperienced users, nevertheless one can get much more with `Solve` than with `NSolve`.

To proceed further first we should evaluate `Rationalize[{0.0625, 0.25 }]` and substitute exact values to the original system. Now we have:

```
system = {Sqrt[EAx^2 + 1/16 EAy^2] EBx + EAx Sqrt[ EBx^2 + 1/16 EBy^2] == 0, 
          1/4 Sqrt[EAx^2 + 1/16 EAy^2] EBy + 1/4 EAy Sqrt[EBx^2 + 1/16 EBy^2] == 0, 
          EAy - EBy == 0, 
          -1 + 4 EAx^2 + EAy^2 == 0, 
          -1 + 4 EBx^2 + EBy^2 == 0,
          -8 + ct + EAx - EBx == 0};
```

Although there are $6$ equations for $5$ variables the system is not contradictory since the equations are not independent and can be reduced to a system of $5$ equations.

The warning returned by `NSolve` appears to be false since it seems a reminiscence from what can be observed with

```
Reduce[system, {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}];
```

> ```
> Reduce::useq: The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s)
> {0==-(1/2) Sqrt[1+12 EAx^2],0==-(1/2) Sqrt[1+12 EAx^2]}. 
> A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram 
> Language functions. >>
> ```

One can figure out that the problem with warning is not harmful. Evaluate `Reduce[0 == -(1/2) Sqrt[1 + 12 EAx^2], EAx]`. 
In fact, we get `6` solutions if we assume `ct` is real and allowing  different variables to be complex:

```
Solve[ Join[ system, {ct ∈ Reals}], {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}]
```

[image]

When playing with the domain specification `Reals` we can find only completely real solutions, there will be only two of them:

```
Solve[ system, {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}, Reals]
```

> ```
>   {{ct -> 7, EAx -> 1/2, EAy -> 0, EBx -> -(1/2), EBy -> 0},
>   {ct -> 9, EAx -> -(1/2), EAy -> 0, EBx -> 1/2, EBy -> 0}}
> ```

If we don't specify the domain there will be more solutions than `6`,

```
ct /. Solve[system, {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}] // Quiet
```

> ```
> { 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 
>   8 - I/Sqrt[3], 8 - I/Sqrt[3], 8 + I/Sqrt[3], 8 + I/Sqrt[3]}
> ```

To summarize `Reduce` is to reduce equations and logic statements yielding sometimes more than one expects, for a more detailed discussion see [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129).

Comment: "Basically one could belive there should be one to one correspondence between Solve and NSolve results" I would only believe this in the case where the solution set over the complexes is finite.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  "One" is assumed to mean a newcomer, not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

The infinite set of the solutions of the system under consideration  can be found by 
`Reduce[Rationalize[{Sqrt[EAx^2 + 0.0625 EAy^2] (EBx) + (EAx) Sqrt[
       EBx^2 + 0.0625 EBy^2] == 0, 
   0.25 Sqrt[EAx^2 + 0.0625 EAy^2] EBy + 
     0.25 EAy Sqrt[EBx^2 + 0.0625 EBy^2] == 0, 
   EAy - EBy == 0, -1 + 4 EAx^2 + EAy^2 == 0, -1 + 4 EBx^2 + EBy^2 == 
    0, -8 + ct + EAx - EBx == 0}], {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}, Reals]`

> ((ct==7&&EAx==1/2&&EAy==0)||(ct==9&&EAx==-(1/2)&&EAy==0))&&EBx==-8+ct+EAx&&EBy==EAy

Comment: Would you explain what you mean by "infinite set of the solutions of the system". There is only a finite set of solutions, unless you refer to an (incorrect) warning of the system.

Comment: @Artes One cannot solve for all variables; it is a parametrized solution set.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The system takes it as such but it's not, evaluate e.g.  `Reduce[Rationalize[system], {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}, Reals,Backsubstitution -> True]`  or assume only `ct` to be real.  Curiously, the system without specifying the domain does not resolve a simple equation `0==-(1/2) Sqrt[1+12 EAx^2]` which seems to be a bug.

Comment: @Artes (1) The ideal in question has mixed dimension and most solver methods will find the highest dimensional component (`Reduce` will find all of them). The "generic" solution set is the highest dimensional component.

Comment: @Artes (2) If there is are parametrized roots then in general one or another might lead to a parasite solution for different values of the parameter. In this example it might be the case that one branch always is a parasite but this is not so easy to assess in general (and in particular it is problematic for the verifier used in `Solve` to remove parasite solutions).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for a reliable comment. I don't insist there is a bug behind the warning when evaluated `Reduce[system, {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}];` (see my answer)  and I find you've slightly enlightened the issue. Nonetheless I can't see any full dimensional component of the solution set even when all variables are complex.  Evaluating e.g. `{ToRules@Reduce[system, {ct, EBx, EBy, EAy, EAx}]}` clarifies that there is only a finite set of solutions, therefore the results of `Solve[system, {ct, EAx, EAy, EBx, EBy}]` is correct, unless I overlooked something.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If this is the case I hope you add another answer.

Comment: @Artes Sorry, I may have added to the confusion. What I should have stated is that the "polynomialized" system has dimensional components in its solution set. This is the system one obtains by replacing radicals by new variables and their defining polynomial equations. You are correct that the dimensional components are all parasite solutions. Problem for solvers, especially such as `NSolve`, is that the methods used rely on polynomialization and that is problematic if dimensional components are thus introduced, even if they are parasite solutions.